# How can I calculate the predicted means and its standard errors of an interaction term in a Generalized linear mixed model?

Tags: r, interaction, data-fitting, glmm

I built up model using an interaction term using the code:

```
be_model1 <-glmer(number_of_fledged_hatchlings ~ species*nestbox_quality + (1|habitat) + (1|year) , family = poisson, data = be)
```

The  fixed effects "species" comprises two levels: Great tit (GT) and Blue tit (BT)
and the fixed effect "nestbox_quality" as well, namely presumably "high" and presumably "low"

Now I have trouble calculating the fittet mean and its standard errors for the interaction term.

E. g. I want to know the fitted average number of Great tit hatchlings within low quality nest boxes and the standard errors of this fitted mean.

So far I tried the following codes:

```
> allEffects(be_model1, se=TRUE)
 model: number_of_fledged_hatchlings ~ species * nestbox_quality

 species* effect
    nestbox_quality
species    high low
  GT 6.275469   6.869725
  BT 6.547347   5.819534
```

which didn't give me the standard errors, as well as this code:

```
library(ggeffects)
> (ggpredict(be_model1, c("nestbox_quality", "species")))
# Predicted counts of number_of_fledged_hatchlings

# species = BT

nestbox_quality  | Predicted |       95% CI
-------------------------------------
high             |      6.28 | [5.50, 7.16]
low              |      6.87 | [6.07, 7.77]

# species = GT

nestbox_quality  | Predicted |       95% CI
-------------------------------------
high             |      6.55 | [5.80, 7.40]
low              |      5.82 | [5.21, 6.50]

Adjusted for:
*   habitat = 0 (population-level)
*      year = 0 (population-level)
```

for which I failed to get standard errors as well.
And I've tried

```
> pred_model2<-predict(be_model1,type="response")
> 
> tapply(pred_model2,list(species,nestbox_quality), mean)
         high low
BT 6.457035   6.838857
GT 6.498190   5.792777
> tapply(pred_model2,list(species,nestbox_quality), std.error)
         high low
BT 0.10072955 0.10153544
GT 0.08011282 0.05989635
```

Here I did recieve standard errors, but I am a little confused about the predicted means as they differ from the values I obtained using the previous lines of code.

Comment: see `emmeans` package ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract this information from the `effects` or `ggpredict` package output (see below), but `emmeans` may be the easiest way forward.

### simulate example/fit model

```r
form <- fledged ~ species*nestbox_quality + (1|habitat) + (1|year)
dd <- expand.grid(species = factor(c("GT", "BT")),
                            nestbox_quality = factor(c("low", "high"),
                                                 levels = c("low", "high")),
                            year = 2002:2005,
                            habitat = factor(1:10))
library(lme4)
set.seed(101)
dd$fledged <- simulate(form[-2], newdata = dd,
                       family = poisson,
                       newparams = list(beta = rep(1,4),
                                        theta = rep(1,2)))[[1]]
m <- glmer(form, data = dd, family = poisson)
```

### emmeans

Note that emmeans gives predictions on the link (log) scale by default: use `type = "response"` to get count-scale predictions

```r
library(emmeans)
emmeans(m, ~species*nestbox_quality)
 species nestbox_quality emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 BT      low               1.12 0.615 Inf    -0.090      2.32
 GT      low               2.17 0.613 Inf     0.972      3.37
 BT      high              2.17 0.613 Inf     0.970      3.37
 GT      high              4.15 0.612 Inf     2.945      5.34
```

### ggpredict

using `as.data.frame()` will get you the standard errors ...

```r
as.data.frame(ggpredict(m, terms = c("species","nestbox_quality")))
   x predicted std.error   conf.low conf.high group
1 BT  3.051631 0.6151573  0.9139219  10.18955   low
2 BT  8.774919 0.6130930  2.6386237  29.18158  high
3 GT  8.786812 0.6130915  2.6422076  29.22104   low
4 GT 63.122520 0.6121429 19.0163563 209.52765  high
```

Note that `ggpredict` gives predictions on the count (response) scale, but does **not** transform the standard errors back to the count scale (arguably a bug, or at least an "infelicity")

### effects package

`as.data.frame()` to the rescue again:

```r
as.data.frame(Effect(c("species", "nestbox_quality"), m))
  species nestbox_quality       fit        se      lower     upper
1      BT             low  3.051631  1.877233  0.9139219  10.18955
2      GT             low  8.786812  5.387119  2.6422076  29.22104
3      BT            high  8.774919  5.379841  2.6386237  29.18158
4      GT            high 63.122520 38.640005 19.0163563 209.52765
```

These SEs are appropriately transformed.

Comment: Dear Mr. Bolker,

thank you very much for your quick response! The emmeans code worked pretty quick and well :)